# CSS position bottom not going to bottom (in Chrome only)

Tags: css, css-position

I have:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 20%;">
    <table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

In Firefox, the table stretches to the bottom of the div.  In Chrome, it only stretches to the height of the maximum height content within the table.  Anyone know why?

Comment: hi can please provide screen shot

Comment: FYI, this isn't "chrome only." This also happens in Safari, so it has something to do with how **webkit** renders the table. I'm looking through the default stylesheets to try to find an answer, but I'm not coming up with much.

Comment: Also, IE8 renders the same as webkit. Your stretch code only works in Firefox and Opera. The fact that it works in Opera, however, means it's probably *supposed* to work that way.

Comment: Yeah, I thought "bottom" meant that the box would stretch to the bottom of its first non-statically positioned ancestor.

Comment: TBH, your code looks like it should work, but tables don't always play nice. Honestly, this could just be a difference in how those browsers work and you might not be able to workaround it (without javascript anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I've finally got this figured out.

It seems that when a table is given an explicit height, it expands to fit that height in the way you're seeing when you set `top: 0; bottom: 0;` within the absolutely positioned `<div>`.

It further seems that when you use absolute positioning "tricks" to set the height of the table, Firefox and Opera interpret this as if you've set an explicit height, even though you haven't. IE, Chrome, and Safari don't make the same interpretation.

The fix for this is to explicitly set the height of the table. In this case, you'll want it to be the entire height of the `<div>`:

```
table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

As an aside, since you're explicitly setting the height of the table, you'll no longer need to stretch it with absolute positioning, so you can get rid of it, along with the `top, bottom, left, and right` properties.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks. Sorry I didn't figure it out earlier. I got lost in the details looking for a root cause and didn't stop to think about how to just fix it. Glad to have helped.